# Visual C++ implements std::unordered_map with only one std::list?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to implement an `unordered_map` similar to std's. So I look over the source code in `<unordered_map>` and `<xhash>` in Visual C++ 2013. I find the implementation calls `_Init` function in the `unordered_map` constructor. I find that the definition of the function is as follows :

```
void _Init(size_type _Buckets = _Min_buckets)
{   // initialize hash table with _Buckets buckets, leave list alone
    _Vec.assign(2 * _Buckets, _Unchecked_end());
    _Mask = _Buckets - 1;
    _Maxidx = _Buckets;
}
```

The function `_Unchecked_end()` just returns `_List.Unchecked_end()`:

```
_Unchecked_iterator _Unchecked_end()
{   // return iterator for end of mutable sequence
    return (_List._Unchecked_end());
}
```

And the `begin()` of the `std::unordered_map` just returns `_List.begin()`...

I think that the `find()` function of the `unordered_map` with only one list can't meet the constant complexity in average case .

So... How on earth does  VC++ implement `std::unordered_map`?

Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. In my opinion, the implementation of `unordered_map` should be a vector with **many lists** (Init with different iterators of **different** `std::list`s). But I only find **one single list** (Init with iterators of **one** `std::list`). That's the point.

Comment: What does "only one list" mean? You are complaining that `std::list` and `std::unordered_map` have different access complexities; do you understand that they are different data structures?

Comment: If you want to implement your own `unordered_map`, first read [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), understand all about it, understand the concepts behind it (hashes and hash tables), then *don't* read any implementation from highly optimized standard libraries. Those standard libraries are not made to be read and understood easily, but if you know the concepts behind hash tables then you can easily make up your own implementation.

Comment: `_Vec` is a vector of iterators (into `_List`) that delineate each bucket. All of the buckets are chained together into a single linked list, but each bucket can be accessed in constant time just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The textbook implementation of a hash table wish separate chaining is what you say: sort of an array of lists, one list per "bucket."

But if you think about it, there is no need to have a whole bunch of separate lists--you can have just one!  This may improve sequential access performance (n.b. it's unordered, but you can still do things "for each" element in a hash table).

So imagine using one linked list: put all the values in there, and for your array (vector), use pointers/iterators directly into the one linked list.  If you want to know where one bucket starts, it's the same as the textbook solution.  To know where a bucket ends, you can simply look at the start of the next bucket (in constant time).

Another way to look at this is that it is the textbook implementation with one modification: the "next" pointer at the end of each bucket points to the beginning of the following non-empty bucket.  You will immediately see why this improves sequential access--it eliminates the cost of traversing empty buckets (of which there could be loads, since an implementation is not required to ever shrink the hash table, only grow it).

Fun story: the *lack* of this sort of trick is part of what caused GCC and Boost unordered_map to have linear rather than constant-time `erase(iterator)` performance for many years.  For GCC, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41975 .  For Boost, see https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3693 .

Comment: It also makes the iterator trivial to implement.

Comment: @T.C.: indeed, see the "Fun story" I added, that's what happens when your iterators are not trivial to implement I guess.  :)